# Oracle 11g package body

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, package

I'm working on a worksheet for class and came to this question about creating a package. Creating the spec, shown on the same link, was easy. It ran the first time. But the package body has me stumped. I've spend darn near two days fixing one group of only for another to arise.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY dept_pkg AS

  PROCEDURE new_dept (
    p_id          departments.department_id%TYPE,
    p_dept_name   departments.department_name%TYPE,
    p_manager     departments.manager_id%TYPE,
    p_loc         departments.location_id%TYPE
  )
    AS
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO departments (
      dept_id,
      department_name,
      manager_id,
      location
    ) VALUES (
      p_id,
      p_dept_name,
      p_manager,
      p_loc
    );

  END;

  FUNCTION get_avg_sal (
    p_dept_id departments.department_id%TYPE
  ) RETURN NUMBER IS
    v_avg_sal   NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT AVG(salary) INTO
      v_avg_sal
    FROM employees
    WHERE department_id = p_dept_id;

    return(v_avg_sal);
  END get_avg_sal;

  FUNCTION get_department_count (
    p_dept_id departments.department_id%TYPE
  ) RETURN NUMBER IS
    v_emp_num   NUMBER(7);
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(employee_id) INTO
      v_emp_num
    FROM employees
    WHERE p_dept_id = employees.department_id;

    return(v_emp_num);
  END;

  PROCEDURE delete_department (
    p_dept_id departments.department_id%TYPE
  ) AS
    v_num_employees   NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT get_deptartment_count(p_dept_id) INTO
      v_num_employees
    FROM dual;

    IF
      v_num_employees = 0
    THEN
      DELETE FROM employees WHERE p_dept_id = department_id;

    ELSE
      dbms_output.put_line('the department cannot be deleted because there are employees assigned to that department');
    END IF;

  END delete_department;

END dept_pkg;
```

Comment: I'm working on a worksheet for class and came to [this question](https://imgur.com/a/rbAhb6K) about creating a package. Creating the spec, shown on the same link, was easy.  It ran the first time.  But the package body has me stumped.  I've spend darn near two days fixing one group of only for another to arise.  please help

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: A snapshot of the worksheet question is displayed when you click on the blue "this question" in my original comment.

Comment: What compilation errors do you get?

Comment: On the face of ir your code looks okay. So you need to be explicit about what your problem is. We can't help if you don't provide sufficient information.